# Android аккаунты приложений

Tags: android, соцсети

Есть приложение, которое работает в связке с мессенджерами и соц. сетями.
Как проверить, установлен ли аккаунт пользователя на устройстве (Вк, Viber, Instagram)?

---

Проблема заключается в следующем: на устройстве может быть предустановленно приложение (из салона), но пользователь не авторизован в нем, поэтому проверка по наличию пакета на устройстве - не подходит. Нужно проверить наличие аккаунта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите в сторону `AccountManager.getAccounts()`

[документация](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html)

Не забывайте про пермишены.